# Call mediator is throwing an error in WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

When I try to use call mediator within the sequence with blocking="true" its throwing an error while send mediator is working properly. Can someone please highlight where i am wrong.
 
I am using WSO2 APIM 2.6.0

Code:

```
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
       <http method="get" uri-template="http://10.10.10.10:10/XYZ/rest/1.0/abc/{uri.var.userId}"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>             
<respond/>
```

I am getting below error message:

```
INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaGet to url[http://10.10.10.10:10/XYZ/rest/1.0/abc/USERX] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error:
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaGet(HTTPSender.java:109)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:63)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:459)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:286)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:490)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:382)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:88)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:384)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:85)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:164)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:119)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:134)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:75)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
```

Comment: it's a 404. Seems the URL us wrong.

Comment: If I replace Send instead of Call it works. I am unable to identify why call is giving 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before the call mediator.

`<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>`

Comment: Thank you, Call was adding addition URL context parameter, why it was appending the Endpoint with context URL if you know please explain. its working Thanks again.

Comment: By default, it appends the incoming request's latter part (i.e. REST_URL_POSTFIX) to the outgoing request.